# Stop CSS inheritance

Tags: c#, css, css-selectors, blazor

I have a *Blazor component*, which I want not to be afected by the *General Styles* of the projects that use it.

The main problem is that the project that implements this Component, overrides some of the styles in their general `styles.css`, and it breaks the layout (principally because their project overrides some Bootstrap names).

I have been searching and found the *CSS* property `all:revert;` that I could add it to the first line of my component styles like this:

```
* { 
   all:revert;
  }
```

So all the previous code that was modifying the component won't affect it.

But I'm not sure if this is the best solution to this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For modern browsers, I think it's the best solution as it will not override user/browser styles etc. whereas initial/unset or using a browser reset will

Comment: I'm not sure if the asterisk is going to work (try it). If it doesn't work I'll try to apply the style to the top tag of the component. And don't forget to do it over the proper isolated css